# Chain rule with implicit partial differentiation?

Tags: calculus

We have some function $F(x,y,z(x)) = 0$

Now we differentiate both sides with respect to x and we get:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx} = 0 \tag{1}$$

We can now solve for $\frac{dz}{dx} = -\frac{F_x}{F_z}$

But doesn't this contradict itself, because if we subtract $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ from both sides of (1) we get $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx}=0$

What is going on here?

Comment: $$\frac{ d F}{d x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dx} = 0 $$ total and partial derivatives are not the same

Comment: @WW1 I think the confusion about the "total derivative" will vanish if we simply insist that the function $\hat{F}(x) = F(x,z(x))$ has its own name, different than $F$.  (These two different functions shouldn't both be called $F$.)

Comment: $F(x,y,z(x))=0$ is an *equation*, not a function. It's unclear what differentiation of an equation means.